# Tensorflow Dataset api issue

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

Here is my code snippet

```py
features=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7],dtype=float)
labels=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7],dtype=float)
training_data=(features,labels)

train_dataset=tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(training_data)
train_dataset=train_dataset.batch(1)

iter=train_dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
batch=iter.get_next()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    x,y=batch
    a=x.eval()
    b=y.eval()   
    print(a,"---------->",b)
```

**Output**:
    `[1] ---------> [2]`

**Expected output**: `[1] ---------> [1]`.

I've spent 6 hours on this, I was training LSTM model when I got this issue. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that after you decompose `batch` into `x, y` you do not get two plain tensors, but instead you get two iterators:

```py
In [15]: batch
Out[15]:
(<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext_1:0' shape=(?,) dtype=float64>,
 <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext_1:1' shape=(?,) dtype=float64>)
```

Hence, `x.eval()` increases the iterator by one and `y.eval()` increases the iterator once again, causing you to see the values `(1, 2)`.

Instead, do this to run the iterator only once:

```py
with tf.Session() as sess:
    a, b = sess.run(batch)
    print(a,"---------->",b)
```

You should see the expected results.

Comment: Ah!! my god,i didn't see that coming,thank you so much.